# How to display my own errors instead of default errors using pdo connection?

Tags: php, pdo

I want to display my own errors instead of default errors using pdo connection.The error can be categorized as

**1.** If database doesn't exist

**2.** Access Denied

**3.** Host Name InValid

A simple code of PDO connection is

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password); 

} catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo $e->getMessage(); 
}

?>
```

Now, Can I use the if statements in catch section? If so, How can I achieve my output? I Don't want to use `getMessage()` function.

Thanks

Comment: use `getMessage()` to detect what the error is and accordingly display your messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use the [`driver_options`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) param of the constructor to make exceptions being thrown on errors:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

Then in your catch block you'll have to analyze the `code` property of the exception:

```
switch($e->getCode()) {

    ....

}
```

You'll find the list of codes and their meaning in the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/error-messages-server.html)

Comment: It's the correct answer to the question with good references,an example and nice formatted :D And it has no reason to be downvoted

Comment: Thx. Yeah, I assume it was downvoted by accident. There is nothing wrong with using `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` consequently from the constructor. Of course exception messages need to get catched, at least in the outermost level of the application, to avoid that sensitive data will get outputted to the client

Answer (score 0):

As @hek2mgl already shown, you first need to tell the driver you want exceptions. To get the actual error you can have a look at the Exceptions code, like so;

```
...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case 1041: //  Error: 1041 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_OUT_OF_RESOURCES)
            $message = 'MySQL is out of resources!';
            break;

        case ...

        default:
            $message = $e->getMessage(); 
            break;
    }
}
...
```

You can find a list of SQLSTATE error codes here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html

Depending on the driver you might have to have a look at `PDO::errorCode` instead .

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php